# How to get the first occurrence of text inside a DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="provInfoSub hidOverflow floatLeft vertAlignT">
    <specialty><a title="Plastic Surgery" href="check.aspx">Plastic Surgery</a></specialty>
    <br />
    <specialty2><a title="Hand Surgery" href="check2.aspx">Hand Surgery</a></specialty2>
</div>
```

How can I, using JQuery, retrieve only the first text entry, "Plastic Surgery" by stripping away all the HTML/XML code outside of it

Comment: username: SearchForKnowledge... Have you search before asking? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you only have one `specialty` node, you can simply pull its `text()`:

```
$('specialty').text();
```

```js
-> "Plastic Surgery"
```

---

If this truly is HTML it's worth noting that `specialty` and `specialty2` are not valid HTML elements and would fail HTML validation, so you may want to consider changing those. If those are your only `specialty` and `specialty2` elements, you could assign those as `id` attributes:

```
<div id="specialty">...</div>
<div id="specialty2">...</div>
```

And then pull the text using an ID selector instead:

```
$('#specialty').text();
```

Comment: Ya but for readability, you should use `first` somewhere, imho

Comment: @A.Wolff perhaps, but that's surely what comments are intended for. No need to add extra function calls where they aren't really needed.

Comment: You are correct but i don't think an extra function call here would affect performance in any way, just that i prefer readable code but anyway, you got +1 ;)

Comment: Now related but what about using C#?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I'm not a C# developer so I don't know, sorry. That falls outside of the requirements of this question.

Answer (score 2):

in case several speciality tags

```
 $('specialty').first().text();
```

or even better

```
 $('specialty a').first().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(function(){
var valor = $("specialty a").html();
alert(valor);
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uohabuw/